# Vector is not accepting insert as a function

Tags: c++

At the line `temp.insert(it);` I keep getting the error No matching member function for call to insert, which means that at some point in my code temp became something other than a vector. anybody have any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

using namespace std;

vector<int> removeDuplicates(vector<int> stuff)
{

vector<int> temp;
vector<int>::iterator it;

for(vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < stuff.size(); i++){
    //iterator to find stuff
    it = find(stuff.begin(), stuff.end(), stuff);

    //if it not in temp then add it
    if (it == temp.end()) {
        temp.insert(it); //No matching member function for call to insert
    }
}

return temp;


}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{


vector<int> values;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    values.push_back(i);
    values.push_back(i+1);
}

removeDuplicates(values);
return 0;
}
```

well the answers helped me out a lot, but I decided to rewrite the code and here is what I got and it seems to work pretty well

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

using namespace std;

vector<int> removeDuplicates(vector<int> oldvector)
{

// newvector to hold non-duplicates
vector<int> newvector;

vector<int>::iterator it;



for(vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < oldvector.size(); i ++){

    //If it find a value then it returns the first element
    it = find(newvector.begin(),newvector.end(), oldvector[i]);
    if(it == newvector.end()){
        newvector.push_back(oldvector[i]);
    }



}

return newvector;


}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{


vector<int> values;
vector<int> newvalues;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    values.push_back(i);
    values.push_back(i+1);
}



newvalues = removeDuplicates(values);

//Print out the vector without duplicates
for(vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < newvalues.size(); i ++){
    cout << newvalues[i] << "\t";

}

return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help with the original question, i learned a lot.

Comment: `temp` is still a `std::vector<>`, `insert` just takes more than a single argument – see [the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert).

Comment: Also, if your goal is merely to remove duplicates, why not `return std::set<int>(stuff.begin(), stuff.end());`?

Comment: "`find(stuff.begin(), stuff.end(), stuff);`" How did you get *that* to compile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The three (pre-C++11) valid signatures for `std::vector::insert` are:

```
iterator insert ( iterator position, const T& x );
    void insert ( iterator position, size_type n, const T& x );
template <class InputIterator>
    void insert ( iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last );
```

You chose invalid option #4:

```
temp.insert(iterator);
```

That option does not exist, you'll have to chose from one of the three listed above.

---

On a side note (as ildjarn pointed out), C++11 adds more... and takes a few away.  Regardless, none of them would be valid the way you are calling it. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert

Comment: There are now 5 overloads in C++11. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn: Hah!  Ok, fair enough, you ruined my snarkiness by calling me out though :D

Comment: @ildjarn: Ok, so I was going to add them... but then I have to add which were removed in C++11 as well... making the whole thing a lot less fluid.  I just prefaced it.

Answer (score 4):

> *which means that at some point in my code temp became something other than a vector*

No, that didn't happen. More to the point, it **couldn't** happen.

The following function does not exist. There is no [matching function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) that takes just an iterator.

```
temp.insert(it); //No matching member function for call to insert
```

Try, for example,

```
temp.insert(it, 7); // will insert 7 immediately prior to end()
```